# Error comes while unity3d project opens in Xcode

Tags: xcode, error-handling, unity-game-engine

My unity project creates error while opens in Xcode.

The error is

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 
(use -v to see invocation)
```

So project not opens in xcode.

```
Xcode Version : xcode5.0

Unity Version : unity4.0
```

How can i escape from this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity does not support Xcode 5 (last tested with Unity 4.2.1).  I am guessing you also are encountering the following issue when you try to build and run your unity project:

> UnityException: Launching iOS project via Xcode4 failed. Check editor log for details.

In order to resolve your issue, you will need to re-install Xcode 4.  I recommend downloading XCode 4.6.3 by searching for it at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/.  While it is possible to run multiple versions of Xcode side-by-side (i.e. 5 and 4.6.3), my experience is that Unity will always launch Xcode 5, and I wasn't able to able to find a way to change this behaviour even with renaming the 2 Xcode apps (perhaps someone else knows a way?).  In my case, I had no other need for Xcode besides building Unity projects, so I just removed version 5.

Answer (score 1):

I started getting a similar linking error after I had upgraded to Unity 4.2.2 (I've only ever used XCode 5 with Unity for iOS).
To fix it - I just wiped out my whole XCode project directory and re-did the build from Unity.  Everything started working for me again.

So I suggest you just try wiping out your XCode directory and re-creating it from Unity.

If you've got custom code in your XCode project - maybe try generating a new XCode project in a different place just to see if it works.